# Linux merge huge gzip files and keep only intersection

Tags: linux, merge, gzip

I have one tab-separated file called "main.txt" and I am trying to add information to this file from many multiple gz files called "chr1.info.gz", "chr2.info.gz", "chr3.info.gz" and so on, which contain a lot more rows than the main file. Note these files are zipped using gzip and I cannot unzip them first and save them because they are huge files (and I don't have space to do this).

I would like to match the column called "name_id" (6th field) in the main file with the matching columns called "rs_id" in the multiple different files (3rd field), and add the additional information from these files while only keeping the rows in the main file:

The main.txt file looks like this:

```
number maf effect se pval name_id
34 0.7844 0.2197 0.0848  0.009585 snp1
78 0.6655 -0.1577 0.0796  0.04772 snp2
```

The chr1.info.gz like this:

```
use pos rs_id a1 a2 a3 a4
f 10584 snp34 0 0 0 0
g 10687 snp35 0 0 0 0
t 13303 snp1 0 0 0 0
```

The chr2.info.gz like this:

```
use pos rs_id a1 a2 a3 a4
s 13328 snp67 0 0 0 0    
g 10612 snp2 0 0 0 0
t 13303 snp10 0 0 0 0
```

…and so on

I would like to get the file main.all.gz with added info from the other files:

```
number maf effect se pval name_id use pos rs_id a1 a2 a3 a4
34 0.7844 0.2197 0.0848  0.009585 snp1 t 13303 snp1 0 0 0 0
78 0.6655 -0.1577 0.0796  0.04772 snp2 g 10612 snp2 0 0 0 0
```

I have tried with "join" but it looks like it requires unzipping the files, sorting them and and saving them, and I get the message that I don't have enough space on device for this (I don't think I have the correct code anyway):

```
join -1 6 -2 3 <(zcat main.txt | sort -k6,6) <(zcat chr1.info.gz | sort -k3,3 ) > try.txt
```

I have tried with awk but I am definitely doing several things wrong since it gives me an empty file, and I get stuck when using multiple files.

I've been spending a day on this and can't find a good solution, 
Can you please help me solve this?

Thank you very much!
-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in Python.

Read the main file into memory and make a dict out of it (use `name_id` as key).  Then stream each info.gzip file and extend the information in the dict according to what you find.  (Consider what to do if you find information for a line more than once.)

Then write out the dict in the format you require.

Does that approach help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gzip
from collections import OrderedDict

mainData = OrderedDict()  # or just {} if order is not important
with open('main.txt') as mainFile:
  pos = None
  for line in mainFile:
    elements = line.split()
    if pos is None:
      pos = elements.index('name_id')
      mainHeaders = elements
    else:
      mainData[elements[pos]] = elements

infoHeaders = None
for infoFileName in [ 'chr1.info.gz', 'chr2.info.gz' ]:
  with gzip.open(infoFileName) as infoFile:
    pos = None
    for line in infoFile:
      elements = line.split()
      if pos is None:
        pos = elements.index('rs_id')
        if infoHeaders is None:
          infoHeaders = elements
        else:
          if infoHeaders != elements:
            print "headers in", infoFileName, "mismatch"  # maybe abort?
      else:
        key = elements[pos]
        try:
          mainData[key] += elements
        except KeyError:
          pass  # this key does not exist in main

with gzip.open('main.all.gz', 'w') as outFile:
  outFile.write(' '.join(mainHeaders + infoHeaders) + '\n')
  for key, value in mainData.iteritems():
    outFile.write(' '.join(value) + '\n')
```

My result was this:

```
number maf effect se pval name_id use pos rs_id a1 a2 a3 a4
34 0.7844 0.2197 0.0848 0.009585 snp1 t 13303 snp1 0 0 0 0
78 0.6655 -0.1577 0.0796 0.04772 snp2 g 10612 snp2 0 0 0 0
```

It does not expect or produce tab-separated files (but uses spaces for everything).  Your example data did not *look* like it was tab separated ;-)  But you can change the `' '` (space) in the output code (last lines) to `'\t'` to use tab as separator.

Comment: Hi Alfe, Thank you for your help. I have never used Python, so I was looking for a way to do this in Linux, but I guess Bash is not ideal for this type of manipulations? I also tried in R but it takes too long to upload the .gz files. I can try this script, but I don't understand it so I won't be able to modify it much… for example, all the files are tab separated (although the example was not reflecting this…sorry..), and I would like a tab separated gz file as the output, ideally sorted as the main file, but I think that won't be a problem to sort after…

Comment: Is there no way to do this in other languages? If not I guess I'll have to learn Python at least to be able to do this…

Comment: Of course this is possible in other languages :-)  But my choice would be Python.  And it's worth learning it, believe me.  The tab-issue:  the parsing uses just `str.split()` which simply splits a string into a list of its words (throwing away all whitespace separators), so it also works for tab-separated input.  Only on the output you will need to use `'\t'.join(…)` instead of `' '.join(…)`, so that change should be no problem.

Comment: To keep the output in the order of the input you can simply use an ordered dict.  See the change in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this and for the extra comments to help me understand! I will try Python out, it looks like it is a very useful alternative to R for big data!

Comment: Just the first step in Python seems to take a long time (more than 10 minutes…) and takes too much memory (it froze my computer) so I had to interrupt it, it was taking too much time in R too… is there any way to do this in a less time consuming way?

Comment: Then I guess that the `main.txt` file is rather large as well.  I misinterpreted you then because I thought only the info files were huge.  Okay, in this case you should chunk the input instead of reading it into memory all at once.  You could do this using the unix tool `split` or in the Python script.